# Stage does not change to another

Tags: java, libgdx

I have 2 stage which named "stagemain" and "stage" and gamescreen in my programme, first stagemain comes and I click "new game", and game starts. Character dies and stage comes. In that 2nd stage, there is a homebutton image. I added it clickListener, so it leads to 1st screen(stagemain)... But I faced with a problem. When I click that homebutton, 1st screen(stagemain) is coming and suddenly 2nd screen(stage),where I click button first, is appearing again. I click homebutton, stagemain appears for about 0.5 second and then it comes back to stagemain. I tried to explain what is happening in my problem, I hope I succeed.. Thanks

This is that homebutton image's clickListener codes. in gameState = 0, stagemain comes... in gameState = 2, stage comes. In addListener codes, I wrote stagemain's preferences.

```
 Texture homeButtonTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("homebutton5.png"));
    Image homeButtonImage = new Image(homeButtonTexture);
    homeButtonImage.setPosition(4*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4+Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/22);
    homeButtonImage.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

    homeButtonImage.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            if(gameState == 2){
                gameState = 0;
                birdY = 2 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;   // Oyunu tekrar başlatırsak kuşun yerini ayarlıyor

                Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stagemain);

                Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
                Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                stagemain.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

                stagemain.getBatch().begin();                                                                                    // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                stagemain.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());               // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                stagemain.getBatch().draw(bird, birdX, birdY, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
                stagemain.getBatch().end();                                                                                     // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                stagemain.draw();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(homeButtonImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your listener is executed once when the button is tapped, not continuously like in your render method. It doesn't make sense to draw anything inside the listener, only to change state. Your render loop should react and draw the appropriate screen based on whatever the game state is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should I move this button's codes in the stage of render method ? It's now in onCreate method.

Comment: That's one way to do it. Something like a switch statement that determines what to draw based on your gameState parameter would make sense.

Comment: I changed It to switch-case statement and put it into render It doesn't work :( , besides, there is play again button which is next to the homebutton, works well with if statement

Comment: I cant really debug without seeing the code. Maybe post on the LibGDX forum so it can be more of a discussion. It seems you haven't quite got a handle on execution order and lifecycle but it's hard to know for sure without seeing more code.